# 1password Windows desktop app: Is there a way to display all users and groups that have permission to a vault?

Tags: 1password

I would like to see the full list so that I can provide clear instructions to our 1password admin about which groups or users should be added or removed.

I only see the total number of people. I do not have admin permissions.

[image]

Comment: Ask your admin for the list of users so you can instruct him on which to remove?

Comment: Listing users is typically something only elevated users have access to on my systems, 1Password, is no different. You don’t have the necessary permissions to list all the users with access to the vault.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did, it's a very inefficient way to get things done.

Comment: @RetoHöhener Yes, well it is the admin's job/responsibility to mange deletion/addition of users not your.

Comment: @Ramhound I disagree. Knowing which users have permissions to a vault is essential for security. How else could I decide if it is ok to add a password for a system in the future, if I don't even know who can access it? In my opinion, the same is true for cloud storage systems like Dropbox.

Comment: @RetoHöhener - You asked how you can see a list of users with access to your vault, and my response to your statement, is you cannot since you are not an Administrator, why are you providing instructions to your 1Password Administrator without actually being a 1Password Administrator?  I was just pointing out that for instance, as a non-Administrator, most systems prevent your managing the users on the system itself.

Comment: @Ramhound My admin asked me to (probably didn't know that I cannot see this info). My question has 2 purposes: 1) I am hoping that someone knows a way to do this even though at first glance it does not seem to be possible, and 2) to let 1password know about what their users want.

Comment: We are not 1Password support, so this community, isn’t the proper place to provide feedback to 1Password about their application. There isn’t a workaround, your user, doesn’t have the permissions required to view the users with access to the vault

Comment: @Ramhound On StackOverflow it is very common for companies to monitor their product's tags. Anyway, my primary intent is to find a solution for my very specific problem. It's fine if you do not know a solution.

Comment: @RetoHöhener - It’s not that I don’t know of a solution, there just isn’t a solution to your problem, 1Password uses role based security.  If my answer isn’t helpful or isn’t what you want, so be it, but you absolutely will not see any change to 1Password because of this question.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to see the full list so that I can provide clear instructions to our 1password admin about which groups or users should be added or removed.

> I only see the total number of people. I do not have admin permissions.

What you want is impossible without Administrator access, or your Administrator giving you the appropriate role based access, to the company’s 1Password vault.

Looking at the available permissions, a 1Password Team account can be given, you should ask for your user account to be given the *Manage All Groups* role. Which will give you the ability, to “Manage membership, vaults, and permissions for all custom groups”, by being able to manage the vaults you will be able to see which users have access to the vault.

Your Administrator can also export the information about the 1Password Team to a CSV